# Laravel - Resource no devuelve las propiedades que tengo definidas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

tengo un modelo que se llama **UserCar** definido de esta forma

```
<?php

 namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCar extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'user_cars';

    protected $fillable = ['id','name','model_id','fuelType','....','user_id'];

    public function modelo() {
       return $this->hasOne(CarModel::class,'id','model_id');
   }
}
```

Y mi intención es al obtener el resultado de un item, hacer uso de un **Resource** para poder añadir campos dinámicos si es necesario o tratar los datos

**Resource UserCar**

```
class UserCarResource extends JsonResource
{


    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'name' => $this->name . ' test test',
            'model_name' => $this->name . ' test test',
            'model_id' => $this->model_id,
            'model_text' => 'model name',
            'fuelType' => $this->fuelType,
            'fuelType_text' => 'Gasolina',
            'yearFabrication' => $this->yearFabrication,
            'potency' => $this->potency,
            'enabled' => $this->enabled,

        ];
    }
}
```

Y luego para hacer uso de el, lo hago de esta manera

```
    $car =  UserCarResource::collection(UserCar::where('id',$id)->get());

    dd($car);
```

Esto veo que me devuelve un UserCarResource, pero no veo que me devuelva por ejemplo la propiedad "model_name" que creo de forma expresa en el resource, o bien el nombre que en el resource lo creo expresamente de esta forma **"'name' => $this->name . ' test test',"** concatenando "test test" pues no lo veo en la muestra del resource.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desconozco por qué con `dd` no se visualizan, pero si haces esto seguro ahí aparecen `return new UserCarResource(UserCar::find(1));` y saldrán los datos extra agregados

Comment: Si hago un return como dices veo por pantalla los valores que pongo "$car = new UserCarResource(UserCar::find($id));
        return $car;"

Comment: Pero mi intención es pasar este resource a una vista de blade, para ello lo hago mediante compact, lo hago de esta forma => return view('front.cars.list', compact('car')); pero allí solo veo las propiedades del modelo, no los datos extra agregados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto pasa debido a que `toArray()` es únicamente llamado cuando se **retorna** como una respuesta. Si lees la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction):

> ...and the **JSON responses** that are actually **returned** to your
> application's users.

Si un resource es pasado a una vista (lo cual no es una `respuesta`), no llamará al método `toArray()`. De todas maneras, puedes acceder al método `toArray()` manualmente.

```
$car =  UserCarResource::collection(UserCar::where('id',$id)->get());
 
return view('front.cars.list', ['car' => $car->toArray()]);
```

Si lo que quieres es **transformar** tu Modelo, deberías utilizar **Transformers**. Ya que los resources no deberían utilizarse de esta manera.

Comment: Es curioso, por que yo replico el ejercicio del OP, agregando al array data de forma manual y si me la retorna la data

Comment: si si...añadiendo el ToArray() entonces si funciona..curioso

Comment: entonces @L.Flor en que casos se deben usar resources y en cuales los transformers? gracias